# how to hack tunneling without changing code, or is it possible?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

if one process does "connect(addr_a)"

is it possible for another process (on the same machine), to capture it

and change to "connect(addr_b)", and serve tunnelling transparently ?

thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `tsocks` library on linux and with [ProxifierPE](http://www.proxifier.com/) on Windows.
Both solutions requires a functional [Socks server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS_%28protocol%29)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

But how to do it depends on your operating system and it requires administrator rights to the machine. The most obvious way would be to use the advanced firewall capabilities for your favorite operating system.